What is the purpose of the MUon proton Scattering Experiment (MUSE)?
What is the purpose of the MUon proton Scattering Experiment (MUSE)? We know that when two protons collide together in a accelerator, convert to 4 muon ultimately (each proton decays to two muon)so is it possible by colliding again two muon in muon collider scientists can make a proton?

If you are talking about MUSE, this is an upcoming low energy scattering experiment solely for the collisions of muons with protons (MUSE stands for MUon proton Scattering Experiment). It is designed to test low energy muon proton events, it does not collide muons with one another directly.

I'm not sure what answer you want, as the link you've provided tells you exactly what MUSE is going to be used for. At these energies MUSE will be exploring the elastic collisions of muons with protons, not deep inelastic collisions with the protons constituent quarks or other muons. There are some other things that can be looked at but that is the primary reason that I know of.

I had read that the result of  2 protons  collision is two muons. Is it possible to do the opposite and create a proton from two muons in muon collider?

I was talking about muon collider not about MUSE (which somebody !?change to that)

My original question was What is the purpose of muon collider?

The. You need to reword and clarify the question some, I didn't suggest the edit, you can always revert the changes if you think they don't represent what you're asking. You may even need to change the title because it sounds like you are asking about a specific collider rather than the underlying process. You could reword the question in that "If it's possible for a $pp$ collision to produce muon pairs, is the reverse process also possible?"

There are multiple things happen when you collide two protons. When you say from two protons you are getting muons,and anti-muons in the final state, you are considering a channel (respecting different quantum number conservations). As a simple example consider the Drell-Yan, where two initial quarks form a lepton-antilepton at the final state. There might be one photon which undergoes pair annihilation. Now, there are multiple channels, and for most of the channels, the final state particles are hadrons (which emerge as Jets). Now, if you try to reverse the situation, by colliding $\mu$ or, $\mu^+$, you are definitely going to get quark and antiquarks at the final state, which after hadronization will form baryons (proton) and mesons.
The final note is, to get the proton, you need to have appropriate channel where the final state will have $d$ and $u$ quarks.

What are exactly, ultimate products of collision of 2 protons  regardless of them which convert to energy finally and we can build  2 protons again with them?

I thought its 2 muon isn't it?

https://muoncollider.web.cern.ch/
